# html form into mysql database then onto a table

Tags: php

i have made a php website with several pages all using index.php (hidden= ?page=)/home
so people see the page as localhost/home
we have a signing up form that i have setup to send a email to a person to see, but i want to make some of the infomation to go to a table, i was thinking of writing it to a html file, but that would mean more files and space being used.
i was thinking infomation could go 
FORM -> FORMSEND.PHP ->DATABASE AND EMAIL
then on a page called "teamentries" it shows a table of the following infomation "Team Name Pits    Car No. Ladies/U16" ladies/u16 is only a checkbox and we need to be able to assign poll positions.

ok thanks to jester i have now got this

```
<?php // database add

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "pedalcar", "Rsr12345");
$database = mysql_select_db("pedalcar_pedalcar", $conn);

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO teamentries (teamname, teamtype, teamhistory,carnumber, carhistory, driverone, drivertwo, driverthree,driverfour, pusher, club, sponsor, leader, address, telephone, mobile, email, construction, deconstruction, marshall) VALUES ('".$TeamName."','".$teamtype."','".$teamhistory."','".$carnumber."','".$carhistory."','".$driverone."','".$drivertwo."','".$driverthree."', '".$driverfour."','".$pusher."','".$club."','".$sponsor."','".$leader."','".$address."','". $telephone."','".$mobile."','".$email."','".$construction."','".$deconstruction."','".$marshall."')");?>
```

but it doesn't add any data, to the database!

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: i need to make a form add to a database and then a table read the database

Comment: Use `<form action='storetodatabase.php' method='post'>` to send it to a PHP file for storing them into a database. In the same file use `header()` to relocate to where you have your table and use a `SELECT` statement to grab the information and `echo` to display it.

Comment: hey jester, i dont know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to try and answer this as best as I can without any given code or file names

**index.php**

```
<form action='sendemail.php' method='post'>
  //input tags (e.g. name, email)
</form>
```

**sendemail.php**

```
<?php 
  //Email code that you wrote

  $conn = mysql_connect("SQL_SERVER", "USER", "PASSSWORD");
  $database = mysql_select_db("DATABASE_NAME", $conn);

  $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (name, email) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['email']."')");

  header('Location: table.php');

?>
```

**table.php**

```
<table>
  <?php
  $conn = mysql_connect("SQL_SERVER", "USER", "PASSSWORD");
  $database = mysql_select_db("DATABASE_NAME", $conn);

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
    echo "<tr>";
  }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: i have now got the code at the top of post, but it doesn't add anything to the database. i know it can connect to the database! but i think i have done somthing wrong in the sql part

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make some of the infomation to go to a table

You mean an html table element or a db table?

> I was thinking of writing it to a html file

You do not need to write a html file to do this, you can produce html output with a php script dinamically (or better populating a div with form inputs using javascript); submitting the form to a save and show php script (form action="showAndView.php"), browser will open a page that executes the query with the form data (sent with POST method, for example)checking data to avoid resubmit on browser refresh into this page, and then with the same data, populates a table. 
No need to create an html file for each form submission!

Edit: expand answer with comment data

As explained, then you can create a php page that saves to db with a query your form data using the $_POST array, which stores your submitted form data sent when you submit the form (if the form method="POST", but you could also use GET method with $_GET array, depending on what you need to do with the data), and then uses that very same array to populate the table
You need to escape your data to be sure nothing bad will happen (malevolent data)

```
//Escaping html data
$formElementName1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['formElementName1'], ENT_NOQUOTES | ENT_HTML5);
$formElementName2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['formElementName2'], ENT_NOQUOTES | ENT_HTML5);

//Escaping mysql data
$value1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['formElementName1']);
$value2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['formElementName2']);

/Saving to db
$db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO your_table (column_1,column_2) VALUES($value1,$value2);

//HTML output
echo "<table>
<tr><td>Title 1</td><td>Title 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>".$formElementName1."</td><td>".$formElementName2."</td></tr>
</table>";
```

Remember to insert query error control and to check data duplicate